# Trimming text before or after pasting in Excel

Tags: excel, string, vb.net, text

I want to paste a string from a `TextBox` in `VB.NET` to an Excel Sheet using `Clipboard` Class:

```
txtBox.SelectAll()
Clipboard.SetText(txtBox.SelectedText)
Sheet.Range("B5").Select()
Sheet.Paste()
```

However, the string I obtain finally in my Excel Application is very huge because it ends with multiple and unnecessary spaces and the column I use to pasting it looks very ugly.

There's a way to trim or delete those blank/spaces in the copied string using `VB.NET`?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Now I have a new question related. If I have a `DataGridView` and I suffer from the same problem, how can I trim the text in this case? This is my code:

```
dgv1.SelectAll()
dgv1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dgv1.GetClipboardContent())
```

Comment: A little off topic, but it's usually not a good idea to mess with the user's clipboard, especially when you could simply set the range/cell's value directly instead of pasting into it...it would actually require less code to do it that way too

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I can't define an specific range because I am exporting different tables, some of them are with few rows and columns and others are very huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out String.Trim()

```
Clipboard.SetText(txtBox.Text.Trim)
Sheet.Range.Select("B5")
Sheet.Paste
```